# How should I let the user choose hours and minutes in iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, time

I have an iOS application, and I want the user to be able to choose/input a certain number of hours and minutes in a clean fashion. I've tried using UIDatePicker, but none of the provided formats suit my needs. I'm not having them choose a certain time in the future, just straight hours and minutes. How should I do this? Some form of a stepper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom UIPickerView should be enough, You know it's only hours and minutes so fill two components, one from 1 to 24 and the second one from 00 to 59

Answer (score 2):

When using UIDatePicker with

```
UIDatePicker datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

You can set the Time Format by setting a locale

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];
datePicker.locale = locale; 
datePicker.calendar = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];
```

With this you should be able the exact time format you want to have

If you want to scroll to the actual time you can use

```
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date] animated:YES];
```

Comment: The Apple documentation says that the "locale" property of UIDatePicker is deprecated

Comment: You could also set the calendar and the timezone because this is what locale basically sets